# How to do list expansion in sql.functions.struct?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I want to be able to pass a `n` length list of column names to `struct`, but I don't want to have to hardcode every column into `struct`. List expansion doesn't seem to work with `struct`. Is there a way to do this?

I am on Spark `2.3.x`, and I cannot upgrade (if this is a version issue) since this is a work cluster.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def randomInt = scala.util.Random.nextInt(100)

val zipData = sc.parallelize(
  Seq.fill(10){(randomInt, randomInt, randomInt)}
).toDF("x", "y", "z")

val cols = Seq("x", "y", "z")
val mappedCols = cols.foldLeft(Seq[Column]())((x, c) => x :+ col(c).alias(c))

// this doesn't work
zipData.withColumn("zipped", struct(mappedCols.head, mappedCols.tail: _*)).show

// it seems only hard coding work
zipData.withColumn("zipped", struct(mappedCols(0), mappedCols(1)).show
zipData.withColumn("zipped", struct(col("x"), col("y")).show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.withColumn`

```
zipData.withColumn("zipped",struct(mappedCols: _*)).show()
+---+---+---+------------+
|  x|  y|  z|      zipped|
+---+---+---+------------+
| 56| 46| 12|[56, 46, 12]|
| 80| 20| 20|[80, 20, 20]|
| 27| 82| 85|[27, 82, 85]|
| 89| 42| 45|[89, 42, 45]|
|  0| 75| 58| [0, 75, 58]|
| 97| 77| 54|[97, 77, 54]|
| 55| 32|  0| [55, 32, 0]|
| 82| 12| 97|[82, 12, 97]|
| 66| 82| 42|[66, 82, 42]|
| 61| 70| 95|[61, 70, 95]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

Using `.selectExpr`

```
val mappedCols=zipData.columns.mkString("struct(",",",") as zipped")
zipData.selectExpr("*",mappedCols).show()
+---+---+---+------------+
|  x|  y|  z|      zipped|
+---+---+---+------------+
| 41| 41| 51|[41, 41, 51]|
| 41| 54| 19|[41, 54, 19]|
| 54| 48| 13|[54, 48, 13]|
| 12| 90| 95|[12, 90, 95]|
| 76| 21| 44|[76, 21, 44]|
|  7| 29| 33| [7, 29, 33]|
| 66| 10| 92|[66, 10, 92]|
| 82|  4| 19| [82, 4, 19]|
|  8| 38| 97| [8, 38, 97]|
| 71| 51| 18|[71, 51, 18]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

Using `.select`

```
zipData.select(zipData.col("*"),struct(mappedCols: _*).alias("zipped")).show()
+---+---+---+------------+
|  x|  y|  z|      zipped|
+---+---+---+------------+
| 41| 41| 51|[41, 41, 51]|
| 41| 54| 19|[41, 54, 19]|
| 54| 48| 13|[54, 48, 13]|
| 12| 90| 95|[12, 90, 95]|
| 76| 21| 44|[76, 21, 44]|
|  7| 29| 33| [7, 29, 33]|
| 66| 10| 92|[66, 10, 92]|
| 82|  4| 19| [82, 4, 19]|
|  8| 38| 97| [8, 38, 97]|
| 71| 51| 18|[71, 51, 18]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

Comment: I accepted your answer. I also found expanding the string column is allowed via looking into their github. Also, the string expansion I posted as an answer is much faster than using the mappedCols or at least it is faster for me.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the implementation on github, we can only expand the string names; that is, the following works

[sql.functions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala)

```
zipData.withColumn("zipped", struct(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)).show
```